# Make 'find -regextype egrep' as alias

Tags: bash

I am just starting learning regex and want to use it instead of others everywhere for practice.

I encounter such a situation when tried to find files with extensions `sh or md`

```
$ find . regex ".*\.(sh|md)$"
.
./bogus.py
./cofollow.py
./data8.txt
./example.sh
./longest_word_2.sh
./posit_param.sh
./cobroadcast2.py
```

Unfortunately it output `/bogus.py`,

I notice the BRE rules and tried escape `()`

```
$ find . -regex ".*\.\(sh|md\)$"
#get nothing return
```

After series of search, I got -regextype solution [Regular Expressions - Finding Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions)

```
$ find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex ".*\.(sh|md)$"
./example.sh
./longest_word_2.sh
./posit_param.sh

$ find . -regextype egrep -iregex ".*\.(sh|md)$"
./example.sh
./longest_word_2.sh
./posit_param.sh
./table_regex_bat.md
```

Additionally, a nice modular solution

```
$ find -type f | egrep ".*\.(sh|md)$"
./example.sh
./longest_word_2.sh
./posit_param.sh
./table_regex_bat.md
```

However, there is a shortcut in BSD to accomplish such a task
with a `-E` predicate.

```
$ /usr/bin/find -E . -regex ".*\.(sh|md)$"
./example.sh
./longest_word_2.sh
./posit_param.sh
```

I am determined to exclusively take the GNU tool in order to make my codes and skills portable.

So I am starting to alias  'find -regextype egrep`,
Unfortunately find obtain the $1 as path.

How could I solve them problem in a handy way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use an `alias` to pass arguments around. They are not portable and useful only on interactive shells. Use a function instead and pass the arguments as paths needed

```
regexFind() {
    (( "$#" )) || { printf 'Insufficient arguments provided \n' >&2; return 1; }
     find "$1" -regextype egrep -iregex ".*\.(sh|md)$"
}
```

and call the function as

```
regexFind "/home/foo/bar"
```

---

Also to add to your findings, note that `bash` also has an intrinsic way to glob files. You just need to enable a couple of extended shell options to make it work. The `-s` enables the option and `-u` disables it.

The `nullglob` allows to ignore un-expanded glob results as valid matches. So assuming you want to match files ending with `*.sh` and `*.md`, you just need to navigate to that particular directory and do

```
shopt -s nullglob
fileList=(*.sh)
fileList+=(*.md)
shopt -u nullglob
```

and print the results to see below. Remember to quote the expansion to prevent the filenames from undergoing Word-Splitting.

```
printf '%s\n' "${fileList[@]}"
```

Comment: Why do use printf '...\n' instead of echo? Is it considered to be more portable or better-practice?

Comment: @BenjaminGoodacre, see [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803), Also, here `printf` allows printing one file per line.

Answer (score 5):

Note that GNU `find`'s default regexps are not BRE, but regexps from some ancient versions of GNU `emacs` (some sort of hybrid between BRE and ERE where for instance, `+` is supported, but you need `\(...\)` and `|` is supported, but as `\|`).

With BSD `find`, the default is BRE, and you can use the `-E` option to enable EREs, so there, it's just a matter of:

```
alias efind='find -E'
```

or:

```
efind() { find -E "$@"; }
```

In GNU `find`, enabling EREs is with a `-regextype posix-extended` predicate, not option. That predicate must appear after the file names which if present must appear after the options and before the `-regex` or `-iregex` that make use of them.

The GNU `find` syntax is:

```
find [options] [files] [predicates]
                      ^
```

So you need to insert it there (at the position marked with `^`).

So, when defining a wrapper function or script, you need to take that into account: skip all the options and file names and insert the `-regextype posix-extended` right after them.

```
efind() (
  found_predicate=false
  for arg do
    "$found_predicate" || case $arg in
      (-[LPDd]|-[OD]*) ;;  # skip options
      (-*|['()!'])
        set -- "$@" -regextype posix-extended
        found_predicate=true;;
    esac
    set -- "$@" "$arg"
    shift
  done
  
  exec find "$@"
)
```

A couple other notes:

- your first one printed `bogus.py` not because BRE were used but  because you used `regex` instead of `-regex`. `regex` was taken as a file name, not predicate.
- `find . | egrep ...` is not valid because file paths may be made of more than one line. With GNU tools or compatible, you can do `find . -print0 | grep -zE ...` to work with NUL-delimited records (and pipe to `tr '\0' '\n'` if it's for display.

Comment: Works wonderful. This would be a nice top answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.md' \)
```

This would work with all implementations of `find` since it doesn't require support for regular expression matching.

To make this more flexible:

```
suffixfind () (
    dir=$1
    shift

    for suf do
        set -- "$@" -o -name "*.$suf"
        shift
    done
    shift

    find "$dir" -type f \( "$@" \)
)
```

This helper shell function (which would work in any `sh`-like shell) would pick out the first command line argument and put it in the variable `dir`.  Then it would construct a list of `-name "*.<suf1>" -o -name "*.<suf2>" (etc.)` with all the filename suffixes on the function's command line before calling `find` with that list to find files in or under `$dir`.

You would use it like

```
suffixfind /usr sh md txt
```

to find all regular files with names ending in `.sh`, `.md` or `.txt` in or under the path `/usr`.

A slightly more verbose variation of the above using `bash` arrays and `bash` local variables:

```
suffixfind () {
    local dir=$1
    shift

    local names

    names=( -name "*.$1" )
    shift
    for suf do
        names+=( -o -name "*.$suf" )
    done

    find "$dir" -type f \( "${names[@]}" \)
}
```

---

About your mentioning of GNU tools and portability:  Note that GNU tools on non-Linux systems are sometimes available, but with a `g` prefix to the tool names.  GNU `find` would therefore be available as `gfind` to distinguish it from the native `find` implementation on the system.

Your "GNU portable" approach would therefore have to test whether `gfind` was available before testing whether `find` is in fact GNU `find`.  Not until you've done that (possibly by testing the return status and output of `find --version`) can you be comfortable in knowing that you are dealing with GNU `find`.

Comment: And a big portability problem is that you cannot e.g. access GNU find under it's native name `gfind` if you are on Linux. So you are right, the portable way is to use POSIX features only - in special if you can do the job with POSIX features.

Comment: I'm afraid that the OP explicitly stated they want to use a regex match wherever possible (for learning purposes). Although your answer would otherwise be useful, it doesn't satisfy this requirement.

Comment: @TooTea There's a time and place for regular expressions. Finding files using them is neither. Also, the purpose seems to be to create a simple way to search for certain filenames, which is the issue I solved.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree completely with your reasoning, but OP explicitly wants to abuse REs everywhere to exercise their regex-fu. When they want to learn how to tighten screws with a hammer, giving them a screwdriver guide does not really help.